# Obfuscate name of AWS Application Load balancer cookie

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-application-load-balancer

I have an Fargate service setup with an ALB in front of it. I enabled application based sticky cookies, in order to maintain websocket connections between my server and the client. The names of the cookies the ALB sets are as follows: AWSALBAPP-0, AWSALBAPP-1 etc. Is there a way to change this and make the names appear as random strings?

I used aws cdk to provision the resources, and enabled cookie stickiness from the target group of the ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService construct

Comment: posted a solution, still unclear how to set cookie name?

Comment: Sorry, something came up. Commenting on it now

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned you used `ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService construct`

In the [Cdk docs ( ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService construct)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService.html) this construct has a property of [Targetgroup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2.ApplicationTargetGroup.html)

Using ApplicationTargetGroup construct, you can define cookie name

It would be something like this

```
const tg2 = new elbv2.ApplicationTargetGroup(this, 'TG2', {
  targetType: elbv2.TargetType.INSTANCE,
  port: 80,
  stickinessCookieDuration: Duration.minutes(5),
  stickinessCookieName: 'MyDeliciousCookie',
  vpc,
});
```

**Note: Names that start with the following prefixes are not allowed: AWSALB, AWSALBAPP, and AWSALBTG; they're reserved for use by the load balancer.Also , stickinessCookieName parameter depends on the presence of stickinessCookieDuration parameter. If stickinessCookieDuration is not set, stickinessCookieName will be omitted**

Comment: I previously used the targetGroup property in ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService to set the cookie name with targetGroup.enableCookieStickiness() which takes in duration and cookie name as arguments. This sets my application cookie correctly (i.e the cookie from my web server to the client) But my client still gets separate AWS ALB cookies, AWSALBAPP-0 etc. Your solution looks like it will yield the same result. It will just set "MyDeliciousCookie" on the client along with the different AWS cookies

Comment: Ofcourse there will be some cookies which might reserved by AWS lb.

Comment: Yes, hence i am asking if it's possible to obfuscate their names

Comment: Reserved cookies won't be possible other than reserved cookies here is the way i told